# @font face not working on Android

Tags: android, css, fonts, font-face

I am using the following CSS for @font face. It works on my desktop and the IOS devices that I have tested. But it fails on Android:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ReformaGroteskMedium';
    src: url('/css/fonts/reforma_grotesk/26890C_0_0.eot');
    src: url('/css/fonts/reforma_grotesk/26890C_0_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/css/fonts/reforma_grotesk/26890C_0_0.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/css/fonts/reforma_grotesk/26890C_0_0.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I noticed that the fonts generated from http://www.fontsquirrel.com/ (which work) are embeded in exactly the same way except they also have the following line:

```
url('SourceSansPro-ExtraLightIt-webfont.svg#SourceSansProExtraLightItalic') format('svg');
```

Is this why my version isn't working, does Android only support SVG?

The version of Android I am using is 4.0.1 on a Asus tablet. It did work fine on a newer Android phone.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the Moz Dev Network from [**THIS ARTICLE**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG/Tutorial/SVG_fonts):

> When SVG was specified support for web fonts was far from being
>   expected. Since the correct font is however crucial for the rendering
>   of a graphic, it was decided to add a font description technology to
>   SVG. It was not meant to concur with other formats like PostScript or
>   OTF, but as a simple means of embedding glyph information for
>   rendering engines.

So i guess that SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics) format should always be used as a "parachute" for allowing any browser/device engine to render fonts correctly.
Anyways i didn't find anything official about Android 4.0.1 and font importing, but i strongly suggest to always use also SVG format when importing a Font.

Comment: ok thanks, I will test it by adding svg on Monday when I have access to that Android tablet again.

Answer (score 0):

You might be facing this Android bug:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=73945

According to them it is fixed on Android 4.4 but not on previous versions :(