# Chrome for Android Refuses to Render Custom Font

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, fonts, font-face

I'm using a custom font I found on [Google Fonts](https://developers.google.com/fonts/) for the heading tags in a site I'm working on. It works fine in Chrome for Windows using any of the methods described in the [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started#a_quick_example) guide. However, the font wouldn't render in Chrome for Android, in fact it doesn't even fall back to my secondary choice which is *'Impact'* and is considered 'web safe.' So I downloaded it locally, [converted it](https://onlinefontconverter.com/) to every relevant format, and using [this guide on @font-face](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/) produced the following CSS which did not solve the problem:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Oswald';
    src: local('assets/fonts/Oswald-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         local('assets/fonts/Oswald-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
         local('assets/fonts/Oswald-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
         local('assets/fonts/Oswald-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
         local('assets/fonts/Oswald-Regular.svg#Oswald') format('svg');
    src: url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald') format('truetype');
}
```

Then I found a [solution using media queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20890489/font-face-declarations-dont-work-in-android-4-3-internet-browser) and produced the following CSS, which also did not work:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Oswald';
        src: local('assets/fonts/Oswald-Regular.svg#Oswald') format('svg');
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 720px) and (orientation:portrait) {
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Oswald';
        src: local('assets/fonts/Oswald-Regular.svg#Oswald') format('svg');
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1280px) and (orientation:landscape) {
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Oswald';
        src: local('assets/fonts/Oswald-Regular.svg#Oswald') format('svg');
    }
}
```

In both solutions I'm using the following simple CSS to use the font:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: "Oswald", "Impact", "Charcoal", sans-serif;
}
```

This is becoming quite the thorn in my side and it's holding me up because I can't present it to the customer until the prototype works on mobile. Any help would be enormously appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: does this help at all? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14287465/font-face-not-loaded/14287894#14287894

Answer (score 2):

Generate your font face using **https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator**. It'll give you everything ready made, you have to just put it in the right place.

But I also think `@font-face` don't work with **Opera Mini 8**